# Error in bind_param() function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, glob

This code records all file names from a certain directory. The file names will be stored to a specific database table. This is my code

```
<?php
$user_dir = "fetz/";
$table_name = "fetz";
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mdrsusr");
if(!$connect) {die();}
foreach (glob("$user_dir*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo $filename."<br />";
    $query = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO ? SET img_link='?'");
    $query->bind_param("ss", $table_name, $filename); //this part *
    if(!$query) {die();}
    $query->execute();
}
$query->close();
$connect->close();
?>
```

*** - this part has an error that states

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
```

Comment: call mysqli_error after the prepare

Comment: so I put it and returns  
`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your query which causes you to not have a valid mysqli statement object.

```
INSERT INTO ? SET img_link='?'
```

should be (you don't need the quotes around your parameter)

```
INSERT INTO ? SET img_link=?
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO table SET = ...` [is valid MySQL syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my error. This

```
$query->bind_param("ss", $table_name, $filename);
```

cause the error so I remove `$table_name` and extra `s` and became

```
$query->bind_param("s", $filename);
```

Which actually does its magic.
I also used the first answer.

Comment: Yes, you can't use identifiers (table names, column names, etc.) as parameter placeholders.

Comment: So in other words, you changed it to `$query = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO $table_name SET img_link=?");` and `$query->bind_param("s", $filename);`